# Is it possible to use a different URL for the API calls from what I use for the website?

Tags: magento2

What I want to do is:
Site URL: example.com
API URL: api.example.com

And how can I do this?
I m currently using magento 2.4.5

I would like the api url to be only for API calls not for the whole site again.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible, obviously you need to configure virtual host / subdomain on your sever and then you can just configure multiple website for your magento site after that connect subdomain with the website that you just created on magento.

> https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/multi-sites/ms-overview.html